# DataFrame to String

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stringio

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
TESTDATA = StringIO(txt)
df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA,names=['col1'])
```

where

```
txt="The lion (Panthera leo) is a species in the family Felidae;it is a muscular, deep-chested cat with a short, rounded head, a reduced neck and round ears, and a hairy tuft at the end of its tail. The lion is sexually dimorphic; males are larger than females with a typical weight range of 150 to 250 kg (330 to 550 lb) for males and 120 to 182 kg (265 to 400 lb) for females. "
```

When I run the above code I get output as:

```
The lion (Panthera leo) is a species in the family Felidae;it is a muscular deep-chested cat with a short   rounded head    a reduced neck and round ears   and a hairy tuft at the end of its tail
```

I get 4 different columns with last column labeled as col1. But What I want is single column with full data. How to achieve it? I want to convert txt data to dataframe with single column.

Comment: firstly, you dont need the STRINGIO with if else, i guess if you try `pd.compat.StringIO()`, it adjusts the compatibility. Check it once. Secondly put the seperator while reading the csv as anything eg `\t` which does not exist in the file and it will read with just 1 column

Comment: @anky_91 I just did the way you told,Still no change in output.

Comment: `pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO("""The lion (Panthera leo) is a species in the family Felidae;it is a muscular, deep-chested cat with a short, rounded head, a reduced neck and round ears, and a hairy tuft at the end of its tail. The lion is sexually dimorphic; males are larger than females with a typical weight range of 150 to 250 kg (330 to 550 lb) for males and 120 to 182 kg (265 to 400 lb) for females."""),
            header=None,sep='\t')` this works for me

Comment: @anky_91 I tried the syntax in other way because of which output I didn't got output.Thanks that helps!!

Answer (score 1):

When you are reading the data using `pd.read_csv` the default delimiter is a comma `,`, you need to explicitly pass `sep=';'` to `pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=';')` if you want to split it by different delimiters or use a delimiter that is not in the file to ignore all the delimiters like `sep='###'`

Comment: or you can also just add `escapechar` to `read_csv` like `pd.read_csv(TESTDATA,names=['col1'], escapechar=',')`

Comment: Bu using sep=';',I am getting shape as (0,1). I am getting output as single column in which row is not there.

Comment: @frank Shape is still (0,1) with no row displayed.

Answer (score 0):

> But What I want is single column with full data. How to achieve it? I want to convert txt data to dataframe with single column.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd    
txt="The lion (Panthera leo) is a species in the family Felidae;it is a muscular, deep-chested cat with a short, rounded head, a reduced neck and round ears, and a hairy tuft at the end of its tail. The lion is sexually dimorphic; males are larger than females with a typical weight range of 150 to 250 kg (330 to 550 lb) for males and 120 to 182 kg (265 to 400 lb) for females. "


memory_file=StringIO(txt)
df =pd.read_csv(memory_file, sep=r'\n', header=None, engine='python', names=["cname"])
print(df)
print(df.size)
```